# spring-data-jpa executed a diffrent SQL from what I defined in @Query

Tags: spring-data-jpa, sql-update

I got a jpa repository interface,it looks like:

```
public interface LabelJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Label, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Label> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE label SET audit_status = :auditStatus WHERE id = :id and label.tenant_id in :tenantIds", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateAuditStatus(Long id, AuditResultType auditStatus, Collection<Long> tenantIds);
}
```

when I called method `updateAuditStatus()`, I expected this SQL would be executed:

```
update label set audit_status=? where id=? and tenant_id in(...)
```

however,the SQL that was really executed was this one:

```
update label set audit_status=? where id=?
//missing condition tenant_id in(...)
```

I tried to debug the whole process in code, but failed in following proxy(too much nested),I wanna figure out what happened before SQL executing,and how to make sure jpa will execute SQL defined in @Query,instead of changing it into a new one.

any answer or suggestion will be appreciated